# rcfaces v:image tag doesn't reload

Tags: java, jsp

I have a v:image tag in my jsp page.(Its a RichFaces tag) like this:

v:image width="100%" id="resultServiceChart" imageURL="MonitoringChart.png"

the image file changes every second and I want to reload the tag every second but

it doesn't change. I changed my code and now every time the filename is different and it
worked good.

but after a while I have a lot of images.

I use ajax to change imageURL.

```
var resComp = f_core.GetElementByClientId(params['param1']);
if (resComp) {
    resComp.f_setImageURL(result);
}
```

the file name stored in result

Comment: RcFaces is not RichFaces -- besides that if you don't have to maintain old code, I would recommend to not using JSPs any more, use Facelets instead, which is the standard view technology of the current JavaEE 6

Comment: Concerning your question, you have to show a bit more code than just your image tag in order to allow people to help you.